# Need help with constructing a counter example. Find a map which satisfies the properties below.

Tags: real-analysis

If $X$ is a complete metric space, $P = \{d(x, y) : x, y \in X\}$. Then find $T : X \to X$ such that there is a function $\phi : P \to \mathbb{R^+}$ satisfying

i) $\phi(t) < t$ for all $t \in P-\{0\}$ and $\phi(0)=0$,

ii) $d(Tx, Ty) \le \phi(d(x, y))$ for all $x, y \in X$,

iii) $\phi$ is an upper semi continuous function.

iv) $T$ is not a Banach contraction.

$T : X \to X$ is a contraction when $d(Tx, Ty) \le k d(x, y)$, for all $x, y \in X$ and some fixed $k \in [0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+,\, x \mapsto ln(x+1)$.

Let $\phi := T$.

Comment: Can you please explain how this satisfies the second property?

Comment: $T$ is concave and increasing, so for any $y \geq x \geq 0$ with $y-x = d$, $|T(y)-T(x)| = |T(x+d)-T(x)| \leq |T(0+d)-T(0)| = \phi(d)$.